# MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, jasperserver

i'm trying to configure a jaspersoft report at jaspersoft server. I created a report that executes an stored procedure passing several values.

When I try to run the report passing a long string as an input parameter, the server shows the following error:

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: Error filling report
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'canales'
at row 1 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3607)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127) 
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2293) 
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:239) 
... 15 more
```

Comment: And what is the problem? U have message why you got error / warning.
String that u are passing is longer than column can store and need to bu truncated to maximum capacity of column

Comment: Is "you" really so hard to type?

Comment: Sorry for that, can't fix it now because of 5 min edit limit

Answer (score 3):

To disable errors raised by data truncation first check your currect configuration:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
```

You probably have something like this:

```
STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
STRICT_ALL_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

So simply remove STRICT_TRANS_TABLES or STRICT_ALL_TABLES (depends on storage engine) by executing

```
SET sql_mode = 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';
```

Best solution would be to check length of the string before you execute query, and truncate it if longer than it's possible

Comment: the problem is with the jaspersoft report server. I can run my queries as long as I want in any mysql editor successfully.